# bookshelf.js – how to fetch all records with empty query or no query at all?

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js

Is it possible to fetch all records of a table in bookshelf without a query?

I'v got a Model named Person, and I'd like to retrieve all of its records.

What I am doing currently is this:

```
Person.where('id', '>', 0) ).fetchAll()
  .then((result) => {
    // doing stuff
  });
```

which just doesn't feel right.

I was hoping for something like

```
// using empty querybuilder
Person.query().fetchAll()
```

or

```
Person.all //
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose `model.fetchAll` is the thing you are looking for.

> Simple helper function for retrieving all instances of the given model.

See the [API Reference](https://bookshelfjs.org/api.html#Model-instance-fetchAll) of Bookshelf.js

Comment: How could I have missed that? I've read the bookshelf docs up and down ... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use `Model.fetchAll()`, which fetches a collection of models from the database, using any query parameters currently set on the model to form a select query.